# Update apt repository on the install DVD with Cubic

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository, iso

I'm trying to create a custom install ISO for unattended installation of Ubuntu server on a small IoT edge server. I've successfully created custom iso's in the past, but this time I needed to add packages from a 3rdParty (webmin) and due to its dependencies also the universe/multiverse repo's. After adding the repo's and during the apt-get update step, my repository lists were updated to point to newer package versions. In itself, great! I love having the latest and greatest in security updates, however...

The install iso will be used in a production environment not connected to the internet. So all the packages that are being installed, should come from the install ISO. How can I update the repository on the custom install ISO to include these newer packages? I've tried adding them to the pool/main folder in the appropriate subfolders, but to no avail. What with the 3rdParty packages?

All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I understand the fact that your system will not be connected to the Internet. However, what is your ultimate goal for having the third-party package `*.deb` files on the ISO? Do you want to be able to install those packages in the Live Environment only. Or, do you want those packages to be installed on your system, after you have installed Ubuntu onto your computer? (Or, is there some other goal for having the `*.deb` files on the ISO?)

Comment: The third party deb file would be installed during the install run, that part I have solved right now by installing it to the custom-disk in Cubic, it seems to get copied over successfully to the target system. However to install that 3rd party package inside the Cubic chroot environment, I needed to do an apt-get update, which messed up my lists files. This I have solved temporarily (I don't like this solution much) by reverting the main lists files to the original ones on the source iso. Ultimately, I would like the updated packages to be available on the ISO.

Comment: What do you mean by "my lists files"? Are you referring to `/etc/apt/sources.list` ? Would there be an issue if, in Cubic, you simply did `apt update`, `apt upgrade`, `apt-add-repository <your repository`, and then `apt install <your package>`? This way all of your software would be up-to date and you would also have your 3rd party packages already installed.